# I have two activity.I want to Send the data from second activity to previous activity.First activity have custom Listview

Tags: android, json, listview

I have two activity.I wanna Send the data from second activity to previous activity.First activity have custom List view and bean class.When was i click on second activity,Fist activity fetch the data in form of String.My problem is how i will display the fetch data on custom listview

My First actvity is..

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.adapter.ListAdapterAddItems;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.json.JSONfunctions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class DetaisRESTActivity extends Activity {
    String totalamount,valueid,valueid1,valuename;

    public String countString=null;
   public int count=0;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView   listview;
    public TextView   mTitleTextView;
 public   ImageButton imageButton;
    ListAdapterAddItems adapter;
    public TextView restaurantname = null;
    public TextView ruppees = null;
    String restaurantmenuname,rastaurantname;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;
    public static String RASTAURANTNAMEDETAILS = "RestaurantPizzaItemName";
    public static String RASTAURANTRUPPEES = "RestaurantPizzaItemPrice";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detais_rest);
     //   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.titlebar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
    mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView123456789);


       imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);


        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenuname");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenunameid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("idsrestaurantMenuId5");
        //totalamount = intent.getStringExtra("ruppees");
        Log.i("valueid",valueid);
        Log.i("valuename",valuename);
        Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);
       // Log.i("totalamount",totalamount);
        new DownloadJSON().execute();






    }


    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetaisRESTActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            //  Log.i("123",value1);
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://firstchoicefood.in/fcfapiphpexpert/phpexpert_restaurantMenuItem.php?r=" + URLEncoder.encode(valuename) + "&resid=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid1) + "&RestaurantCategoryID=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid) + "");



            try {

                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenItems");
                Log.i("1234",""+jsonarray);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                     ListModel sched = new ListModel();
                    sched.setProductName(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemName"));

                    sched.setPrice(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemPrice"));

                    arraylist.add(sched);

                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdetails);

            adapter = new ListAdapterAddItems();

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();



            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                {

                    // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
                    ListModel p =(ListModel)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want

                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.getProductName());
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Ruppees: " + p.getPrice());





                    count++;
                    countString=String.valueOf(count);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Item " + (position + 1),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();

                    Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                            countString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                       mTitleTextView.setText(countString);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,QuentityActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("quentity",countString);
                    intent.putExtra("valueid",valueid);
                    intent.putExtra("valuename",valuename);
                    intent.putExtra("valueid1",valueid1);

                    intent.putExtra("name",p.getProductName());
                    intent.putExtra("price",p.getPrice());
                    startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                   // startActivity(intent);

                }
            });
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                    Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,TotalPriceActivity.class);
  startActivity(i);
                }
            });
        }
    }
    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if(requestCode==2)
        {

            String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx",message);
            ruppees.setText(message);

        }
    }
    //==========================
    class ListAdapterAddItems extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel>
    {
        ListAdapterAddItems(){
            super(DetaisRESTActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
            //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arraylist.get(position));
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {



        ViewHolder(View row) {
            restaurantname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamedetailsrestaurant);
            ruppees = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurant);

        }

        // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
        void populateFrom(ListModel r) {
            restaurantname.setText(r.getProductName());
            ruppees.setText(r.getPrice());

        }


    }


















    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detais_rest, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

My Second Actvity is.....

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.json.JSONfunctions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class QuentityActivity extends Activity {
String value=null;
     public String TotAmt=null;
    String Name;
    ImageButton positive,negative;

 int count = 0;
    int tot_amt = 0;
    public String countString=null;
    String Rs,name,price;
    String valueid,valueid1,valuename;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView   listview;
    public TextView ruppees,submenuname,totalruppees,quantity,addtocart;


    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quentity);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        value = intent.getStringExtra("quentity");
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("valuename");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("valueid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("valueid1");
        name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
        price=intent.getStringExtra("price");
        Log.i("valueid",valueid);
        Log.i("valuename",valuename);
        Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);
        Log.i("name",name);
        Log.i("price",price);
        quantity=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurantquantity);
        totalruppees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamequentitytotal1);
        submenuname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamesubmenuquentity);
        ruppees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamequentity1);
        positive=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonpositive);
        negative=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonnegative);
        addtocart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewaddtocart);
        buttonclick();
        addtocart();
        //  value1 = intent.getStringExtra("numericitem");
        //  int numericvalue = intent.getIntExtra("numericitem", 11);
        Log.i("value", value);
        submenuname.setText(name);
        ruppees.setText(price);
        totalruppees.setText(price);
        // new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }


    public void addtocart(){
        addtocart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",TotAmt);
                setResult(2,intent);
                finish();//finishing activity

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quentity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: You can write arraylist.get(position) .MODEL_METHOD_NAME to show your data. You can check this http://www.androidhive.info/2014/07/android-custom-listview-with-image-and-text-using-volley/

Comment: @AkshayMukadam can u change in my code?where i use arraylist.get(postion).MODEL_METHOD_NAME

Comment: You can edit here. holder.populateFrom(arraylist.get(position));

Comment: Use `startActivityForResult()`

Comment: @PiyushGupta check my activity i m already used it

Comment: @AkshayMukadam Can u edit arraylist.get(postion).MODEL_METHOD_NAME in my code?

Comment: Best way is manage you bean class make it common for both activity... When first restart reload you listview with notifydatasetchanged()

Answer (score 3):

```
public void addtocart(){
    addtocart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
        @Override
        public void onClick(View v) {
            Intent intent=new Intent(QuentityActivity.this,DetaisRESTActivity.class);
            intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",TotAmt);
            startActivity(intent);
            finish();//finishing activity
        }
    });
}
```

In the first activity then:

```
@Override
protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState){
     super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
     Intent c = getIntent();
     String mg = c.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
}
```

So now you can show the `String` where you want.

Comment: Can u edit in my code?how to add String value to Custom list view

Answer (score 1):

Do this on second activity class...

```
public void addtocart()

{
   addtocart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener()     
{
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v)     
             {
                  Intent intent=new   Intent(QuentityActivity.this,DetaisRESTActivity.class);
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",TotAmt);
                startActivity(intent);
                finish();//finishing activity

            }
        });
```

}

Now in oncreate() method of first activity class..use this..

```
if(getIntent().hasExtra("MESSAGE"))
{
   String msg= getIntent().getStringExtra("MESSAGE");

}
```

Comment: after fetching the data add this to arraylist and then set the adapter again or use notifydatasetchanged...

Answer (score 1):

Steps to follow:

1. You should have to refresh your list view with updated data.
2. Use `adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();`

   ```
   @Override
   protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
       {
       super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
       // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
       if(requestCode==2)
       {
           String message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
           Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx",message);
           ruppees.setText(message);
           adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();

       }
   }
   ```

Answer (score 0):

You have to refresh the list view.first you have to update the listadapterItems. then do it like below code .

//here update your adapter like below,return the position also from the    activity in onactivityresult

```
 ArrayList<ListModel> updatedarraylist = (ArrayList<ListModel>) adapter
                    .getData();
    ListModel sched = updatedarraylist .get(pos);
    sched.setPrice(message);
    updatedarraylist.set(pos,sched);  
    adapter.setData(updatedarraylist );
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
```

Comment: When i was used  ArrayList<ListModel> updatedarraylist = (ArrayList<ListModel>) adapter
                    .getData(); this line .getData() method not find

Comment: pass your list, ArrayList<ListModel> updatedarraylist = arraylist;

Comment: where i use ListModel sched = updatedarraylist .get(pos);
    sched.setPrice(message);
    arraylist.set(pos,sched);  
    adapter.setData(updatedarraylist );
    adapter.notifyDataSetChanged(); in my activity?

Comment: inside the OnActivityResult()  where you are getting the message

Comment: are you getting the position? you have to pass it from activity A->B then return to B->A

Comment: yes i m getting position but in onactivity method  does not have position variable

Comment: Mu problem is set string value to custom listview

Comment: first you have to pass the position in intent extra on listitem click.you have to get from intent like   int positon=data.getIntExtra("Position"); inside onActivityresult()