# I have two activity.When i was click on first activity list view,second activity open. number of count in first activity also increase

Tags: java, android, android-listview, android-actionbar

I have two activities. When I clicked on first activity in list view, second activity opened .Second activity have one button number of item. when I clicked on second activity number of count goes to first activity. It is repeated process but number of count in first activity also gets increased.

My first activity..

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;
import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.content.res.Resources;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.LayoutInflater;
import android.view.MenuInflater;
import android.view.View;
import android.view.ViewGroup;
import android.view.Window;
import android.widget.AbsListView;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.ActionMode;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ArrayAdapter;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;
import android.app.Activity;

import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.adapter.ListAdapterAddItems;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.json.JSONfunctions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import android.support.v7.app.ActionBarActivity;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;


public class DetaisRESTActivity extends Activity {
    String messagevaluename,totalamount,valueid,valueid1,valuename,pos;

    public String countString=null;
   public int count=0;
    public  String message=null;
    public static   String message1=null;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView   listview;
    ArrayList aa;
    public TextView   mTitleTextView;
 public   ImageButton imageButton;
    ListAdapterAddItems adapter;
    public TextView restaurantname = null;
    public TextView ruppees = null;
    String restaurantmenuname,rastaurantname;

    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;
    public static String RASTAURANTNAMEDETAILS = "RestaurantPizzaItemName";
    public static String RASTAURANTRUPPEES = "RestaurantPizzaItemPrice";

    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
       // requestWindowFeature(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_detais_rest);
     //   getWindow().setFeatureInt(Window.FEATURE_CUSTOM_TITLE,R.layout.titlebar);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));

        LayoutInflater mInflater = LayoutInflater.from(this);

        View mCustomView = mInflater.inflate(R.layout.titlebar, null);
    mTitleTextView = (TextView) mCustomView.findViewById(R.id.textView123456789);

       imageButton = (ImageButton) mCustomView
                .findViewById(R.id.imageButton2);

        imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


            @Override
            public void onClick(View view) {
                Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), "Refresh Clicked!",
                        Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,TotalPriceActivity.class);


                startActivity(i);
            }
        });

        actionBar.setCustomView(mCustomView);
        actionBar.setDisplayShowCustomEnabled(true);

        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenuname");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("restaurantmenunameid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("idsrestaurantMenuId5");
        //totalamount = intent.getStringExtra("ruppees");
        Log.i("valueid",valueid);
        Log.i("valuename",valuename);
        Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);
       // Log.i("totalamount",totalamount);

        new DownloadJSON().execute();






    }


    // DownloadJSON AsyncTask
    private class DownloadJSON extends AsyncTask<Void,Void,Void> {

        @Override

        protected void onPreExecute() {
            super.onPreExecute();
            // Create a progressdialog
            mProgressDialog = new ProgressDialog(DetaisRESTActivity.this);
            // Set progressdialog title
            mProgressDialog.setTitle("Android JSON Parse Tutorial");
            // Set progressdialog message
            mProgressDialog.setMessage("Loading...");
            mProgressDialog.setIndeterminate(false);
            // Show progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.show();
            Toast.makeText(DetaisRESTActivity.this, "Successs", Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
        }

        @Override
        protected Void doInBackground(Void... params) {
            // Create an array
            arraylist = new ArrayList<ListModel>();
            // Retrieve JSON Objects from the given URL address
            //  Log.i("123",value1);
            jsonobject = JSONfunctions.getJSONfromURL("http://firstchoicefood.in/fcfapiphpexpert/phpexpert_restaurantMenuItem.php?r=" + URLEncoder.encode(valuename) + "&resid=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid1) + "&RestaurantCategoryID=" + URLEncoder.encode(valueid) + "");



            try {

                // Locate the array name in JSON
                jsonarray = jsonobject.getJSONArray("RestaurantMenItems");
                Log.i("1234",""+jsonarray);

                for (int i = 0; i < jsonarray.length(); i++) {

                    jsonobject = jsonarray.getJSONObject(i);


                     ListModel sched = new ListModel();
                    sched.setId(jsonobject.getString("id"));
                    sched.setProductName(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemName"));

                    sched.setPrice(jsonobject.getString("RestaurantPizzaItemPrice"));

                    arraylist.add(sched);


                }
            } catch (JSONException e) {
                Log.e("Error", e.getMessage());
                e.printStackTrace();
            }
            return null;
        }

        @Override
        protected void onPostExecute(Void args) {
            // Locate the listview in listview_main.xml
      listview = (ListView) findViewById(R.id.listViewdetails);

            adapter = new ListAdapterAddItems();

            listview.setAdapter(adapter);
            // Close the progressdialog
            mProgressDialog.dismiss();
//listview.invalidateViews();
            adapter.notifyDataSetChanged();
           // listview.notifyAll();
            listview.setOnItemClickListener(new AdapterView.OnItemClickListener()
            {
                @Override
                public void onItemClick(AdapterView<?> arg0, View arg1, int position, long arg3)
                {

                    // Get Person "behind" the clicked item
                    ListModel p =(ListModel)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    // Log the fields to check if we got the info we want
                    Log.i("SomeTag",""+p.getId());
                    //String itemvalue=(String)listview.getItemAtPosition(position);
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Persons name: " + p.getProductName());
                    Log.i("SomeTag", "Ruppees: " + p.getPrice());





                    //count++;
                    //countString=String.valueOf(count);
                    Toast toast = Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(),
                            "Item " + (position + 1),
                            Toast.LENGTH_SHORT);
                    toast.setGravity(Gravity.BOTTOM|Gravity.CENTER_HORIZONTAL, 0, 0);
                    toast.show();

                    //Toast.makeText(getBaseContext(),
                      //      countString, Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();
                       Log.i("postititi",""+position);
                      // mTitleTextView.setText(countString);
                    Intent intent=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,QuentityActivity.class);
                    intent.putExtra("quentity",countString);
                    intent.putExtra("valueid",valueid);
                    intent.putExtra("valuename",valuename);
                    intent.putExtra("valueid1",valueid1);
                   intent.putExtra("id",p.getId());
                    intent.putExtra("name",p.getProductName());
                    intent.putExtra("price",p.getPrice());
                    startActivityForResult(intent,2);
                   // startActivity(intent);

                }
            });

        }
    }


    // Call Back method  to get the Message form other Activity
    @Override
    protected void onActivityResult(int requestCode, int resultCode, Intent data)
    {
        super.onActivityResult(requestCode, resultCode, data);
        // check if the request code is same as what is passed  here it is 2
        if(requestCode==2)
        {
           // aa=new ArrayList();


            pos=data.getStringExtra("POSITION");
             message=data.getStringExtra("MESSAGE");
            message1=data.getStringExtra("COUNTSTRING");
            messagevaluename=data.getStringExtra("VALUENAME");
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx",message);
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx1234",pos);
            Log.i("xxxxxxxxxxx5678count",message1);
            Log.i("messagevaluename",messagevaluename);
            //ruppees.setText(message);
              mTitleTextView.setText(message1);
            imageButton.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {


                @Override
                public void onClick(View view) {
                    Toast.makeText(getApplicationContext(), message,
                            Toast.LENGTH_LONG).show();

                    Intent i=new Intent(DetaisRESTActivity.this,TotalPriceActivity.class);
                     i.putExtra("ruppees",message);
                    i.putExtra("id",pos);
                    i.putExtra("messagevaluename",messagevaluename);
                    startActivity(i);
                }
            });


        }
    }

    //==========================
    class ListAdapterAddItems extends ArrayAdapter<ListModel>
    {
        ListAdapterAddItems(){
            super(DetaisRESTActivity.this,android.R.layout.simple_list_item_1,arraylist);
            //imageLoader = new ImageLoader(MainActivity.this);
        }
        @Override
        public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
            final ViewHolder holder;
            if(convertView == null){
                LayoutInflater inflater = getLayoutInflater();
                convertView = inflater.inflate(R.layout.cartlistitem, null);
                holder = new ViewHolder(convertView);
                convertView.setTag(holder);
            }else{
                holder = (ViewHolder)convertView.getTag();
            }
            holder.populateFrom(arraylist.get(position));

          //  arraylist.get(position).getPrice();
            return convertView;
        }
    }

    class ViewHolder {



        ViewHolder(View row) {
            restaurantname = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamedetailsrestaurant);
            ruppees = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurant);

        }

        // Notice we have to change our populateFrom() to take an argument of type "Person"
        void populateFrom(ListModel r) {
            restaurantname.setText(r.getProductName());
            ruppees.setText(r.getPrice());

        }


    }














        //=============================================================






    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_detais_rest, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.


        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }

}
```

Second activity....

```
package com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin;

import android.app.ActionBar;
import android.app.Activity;
import android.app.ProgressDialog;
import android.content.Intent;
import android.graphics.Color;
import android.graphics.drawable.ColorDrawable;
import android.os.AsyncTask;
import android.os.Bundle;
import android.support.v4.app.FragmentManager;
import android.util.Log;
import android.view.Gravity;
import android.view.Menu;
import android.view.MenuItem;
import android.view.View;
import android.widget.AdapterView;
import android.widget.ImageButton;
import android.widget.ListView;
import android.widget.TextView;
import android.widget.Toast;

import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.bean.ListModel;
import com.firstchoicefood.phpexpertgroup.firstchoicefoodin.json.JSONfunctions;

import org.json.JSONArray;
import org.json.JSONException;
import org.json.JSONObject;

import java.net.URLEncoder;
import java.util.ArrayList;


public class QuentityActivity extends Activity {
String value=null;
     public String TotAmt=null;
    String Name;
    ImageButton positive,negative;
String position;
 int count = 1;
    int tot_amt = 0;
    public String countString=null;
    String Rs,name,price;
    String valueid,valueid1,valuename;
    JSONObject jsonobject;
    JSONArray jsonarray;
    ListView   listview;
    public TextView ruppees,submenuname,totalruppees,quantity,addtocart;


    ProgressDialog mProgressDialog;
    ArrayList<ListModel> arraylist;
    @Override
    protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
        super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
        setContentView(R.layout.activity_quentity);
        ActionBar actionBar = getActionBar();

        // Enabling Up / Back navigation
        actionBar.setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
        actionBar.setBackgroundDrawable(new ColorDrawable(Color.parseColor("#ff0000")));
        Intent intent = getIntent();
        // get the extra value
        value = intent.getStringExtra("quentity");
        valuename = intent.getStringExtra("valuename");
        valueid = intent.getStringExtra("valueid");
        valueid1 = intent.getStringExtra("valueid1");
        name=intent.getStringExtra("name");
        price=intent.getStringExtra("price");
        position=intent.getStringExtra("id");
        Log.i("valueid",valueid);
        Log.i("valuename",valuename);
        Log.i("valueid1",valueid1);
        Log.i("name",name);
        Log.i("price",price);
       Log.i("id1",position);
        quantity=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantcuisinedetalsrestaurantquantity);
        totalruppees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamequentitytotal1);
        submenuname=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamesubmenuquentity);
        ruppees=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.rastaurantnamequentity1);
        positive=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonpositive);
        negative=(ImageButton)findViewById(R.id.imageButtonnegative);
        addtocart=(TextView)findViewById(R.id.textViewaddtocart);
        buttonclick();
        addtocart();
        //  value1 = intent.getStringExtra("numericitem");
        //  int numericvalue = intent.getIntExtra("numericitem", 11);

        submenuname.setText(name);
        ruppees.setText(price);
        totalruppees.setText(price);
        // new DownloadJSON().execute();
    }


    public void buttonclick(){
        positive.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getString =quantity.getText().toString();
                String totalAmtString = ruppees.getText().toString();
                int totAmount = Integer.parseInt(totalAmtString);
                //count = Integer.parseInt(getString);
                count++;
                countString = String.valueOf(count);
                tot_amt = totAmount * count;

        TotAmt = String.valueOf(tot_amt);

                  totalruppees.setText(TotAmt);
                quantity.setText(countString);

           }
        });


        negative.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                String getString =quantity.getText().toString();
                String totalAmtString = ruppees.getText().toString();
                int totAmount = Integer.parseInt(totalAmtString);
                //count = Integer.parseInt(getString);
                if (count > 1)
                    count--;
                countString = String.valueOf(count);
                tot_amt = totAmount * count;

                TotAmt = String.valueOf(tot_amt);

                totalruppees.setText(TotAmt);
                quantity.setText(countString);

            }
        });

    }
    public void addtocart(){
        addtocart.setOnClickListener(new View.OnClickListener() {
            @Override
            public void onClick(View v) {
                Intent intent=new Intent();
                intent.putExtra("MESSAGE",TotAmt);
               intent.putExtra("POSITION",position);
                intent.putExtra("COUNTSTRING",countString);
                intent.putExtra("VALUENAME",valuename);

                setResult(2,intent);
                finish();//finishing activity

            }
        });
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
        // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
        getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.menu_quentity, menu);
        return true;
    }

    @Override
    public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
        // Handle action bar item clicks here. The action bar will
        // automatically handle clicks on the Home/Up button, so long
        // as you specify a parent activity in AndroidManifest.xml.
        int id = item.getItemId();

        //noinspection SimplifiableIfStatement
        if (id == R.id.action_settings) {
            return true;
        }

        return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
    }
}
```

Comment: What is your exact problem?. Get us your code here

Comment: Share your code this explanation is not complete and understandable

Comment: check this link  http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30316455/i-have-two-activity-i-want-to-send-the-data-from-second-activity-to-previous-act

Comment: You need to start your second activity as a child activity using `startActivitiyForResult()` which will push back data (your count) to first activity in `onActivityResult()` method.

Comment: @PiyushGupta can u edit in my code?

Comment: Plz post your code here, We will answer fir that, once u get suitable answer, u can use that answer